# Type '{ title: string; icon: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

please am new to TypeScript. I am trying to pass the list of items from the parent component to the child component in TypeScript but it's not working. can someone please help me out to know what I am doing wrong?

Here,s my code

parent component

```
export type MailRowType = {
  icon: any,
  name: string,
  title: string,
  description: string,
  time: number,
}

const Inbox = () => {
return (
  <div>
    <MailRow name="Emmanuel uzoezie" title="JavaScript" icon={<StarBorderIcon />}/>
  </div>
)
}
```

child component

```
type Props = {
    item: MailRowType
}

const MailRow:React.FC<Props> = ({item}) => {

return(
<div>
 <h2>{item.name}</h2>
<span>{item.icon}</span>
<h4>{item.title}</4>
</div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unwrapping an item in your props, but you don't send any item in your props, to your child element. You need to set your `MailRowType` to your props and then your component should work.

You can see it running in this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-2aohyl?file=App.tsx)

Parent component.

```
const Inbox = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MailRow
        name="Emmanuel uzoezie"
        title="JavaScript"
        icon={<div>test icon</div>}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Child component.

```
export type MailRowType = {
  icon: any;
  name: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  time: number;
};

type Props = {
  item: MailRowType;
};

const MailRow: React.FC<Props> = (props: MailRowType) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{props.name}</h2>
      <span>{props.icon}</span>
      <h4>{props.title}</h4>
    </div>
  );
};
```